# How can I make a child element be constrained by its parent’s width in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an element within another element. The parent is of a certain size. I want the child to be the exact same size, but at the same time have a padding.

If I don't know the exact size of the parent, is there any way to get it to be the same size as the parent and have a padding?

problem:

http://jsbin.com/odemu3/edit

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On supported browsers, set `box-sizing` to `border-box` (CSS3 only). This causes the browser to calculate the width of an element as content + padding + border + margin (as opposed to `content-box` in the CSS1/2 box model):

```
input {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I believe inputs already have this setting by default, but this can also apply to any other child elements whose widths you want calculated like that.

Answer (score 3):

Make the child element `display:block` (which will cause it to fill the width of the parent) and either give the parent padding or give the child a margin. Do not try to specify a width on the child element.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. This does not work for me. It's not filling up the parent. http://jsbin.com/odemu3/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Width calculations are done before any padding/margins are taken into account, so a child with width 100% will be 100% of the parent's, after which margins/padding are added, so you'll end up with something over 100%.

You can fake the effect by putting on a border of the same color as the background. This would work, since you've got a solid background for the child to span over.

Comment: To have the width of an element be calculated as content+padding+border+margin, use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: @BoltClock awesome! I'm using this right now in lieu of a more degradable method. Would give point if you post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but it worked

Remove left and right padding `padding:20px 0;` and set `text-indent:20px;` on `input`

http://jsbin.com/aleta4/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

`block-sizing: border-box` didn't work for my particular problem but there is another way for those coming back to this question:

use `position: absolute` along with `right:0` (or bottom for vertical constraints) to constrain the child to the parent. The parent element should have `position: relative` and it is forced to fit perfectly.